# How to run a while conditional which looks at a position of all lists in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

**[Python 3.7]**

---

I want to run a `while()` condition which looks at the `3rd` position of all lists in a nested list:

*example:*

`list = [[0,2,3,4], [4,3,2,5], [3,4,3,2]]`

```
while list[:][2] != 2:    # ':' denoting all (I know its not correct)
    pass                  # AKA do something
```

I want to do this because in the code I am working on I have parts of a list that require deletion and I need to know when only a specific element is left.

Comment: Why not use a for loop instead?

Comment: @haron68 its a recursive function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
while all((row[2] != 2 for row in list)):
```

or:

```
while any((row[2] != 2 for row in list)):
```

depending on what you really want.